# Standardized library to compress data as a sequence of small pieces C++/C?

Tags: c++, c, compression

I need to compress data for logging by appending short strings to the log file using C++/C. I first tired gzip(zlib), but this makes a symbol table for each short string and actually makes the data longer rather than compressing. I believe the thing I'm looking for is a static Huffman table. Anyway, I was wondering if there was a common algorithm for this. I would much rather a format that anyone could read. I think the answer is no, but this is the place to ask. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried lzo - http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/?

Comment: Why would you tag this as both C and C++?

Comment: I would rather write it in c, but if there is a handy C++ lib that just does it, then that might be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [examples/gzlog.[ch] source files](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) in the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) distribution.  That code was written for precisely this purpose.  It appends short strings to a growing compressed gzip file.